# Fatal error in PHP script Call to a member function execute() on boolean

Tags: php

Can anyone help. This used to work fine on my old server. Then I transferred it across to a new server and I get the same fatal error. From my understanding the `prepare` statement fails and gets a value of `FALSE` but I don't understand whats causing this.

```
$query = " 
        SELECT 
            id, 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        FROM User 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 

    // The parameter values 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
       die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        //echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in index.php:36 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in index.php on line 36
```

Comment: What kind of DB do you use?

Comment: Try turning enabling PDO's exception reporting feature with `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` before using `prepare` so you can see error message.

Comment: @bd808 returns with `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::setAttribute()`

Comment: @Tom Use `bind_param()` if you use `mysqli`; You can't pass the param array to `execute()` with `mysqli` only with `PDO`

Comment: What is $db? Object?

Comment: @vladkras `$db = new mysqli("$host", "$user", "$pass", "$db");`

Comment: @Tom You can't mix MYSQL API's, so you can't just use methods from another class. And catch exceptions which will be never thrown. Also see: http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#example-1880

Comment: Plus 1 for bindParam() before execute

Comment: Thanks guys - seems to be working now :)